# Query result on codeigniter : Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model like this :

```
public function selectRequestPerUser($nama_user) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('nama_user' => $nama_user));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and on controller, I wrote like this :

```
$request = $this->model_request->selectRequestPerUser($this->session->userdata('nama'));
$total_rows = $request->num_rows();
```

The browser gives me error like this :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object
```

I need the result of num_rows for create pagination, thanks for the help.

Comment: since result is already return then why again `num_rows()`. try to print out `$request` and check.

Comment: I use var_dump(). It success like this : array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (33) { ["kode_kantor"]=> string(3) ......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function num\_rows() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751899/call-to-a-member-function-num-rows-on-a-non-object)

Comment: that is i am telling that you have already RESULT IN ARRAY FORMAT, use it directly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of get `num_rows()` in `controller` You need to write a new query for fetching total number of row in your model file and call it from your controller as below.

**Controller**

```
$total_rows = $this->model_request->countPerUser($this->session->userdata('nama'));
```

**Model**

```
public function countPerUser($nama_user) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('nama_user' => $nama_user));
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

And why you getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object
```

because `num_rows()` only work with query instance . We can use `num_rows()` for getting number of rows on array or object.

Comment: What if he wants the results as well ?  Write another function for results ?

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
public function selectRequestPerUser($nama_user) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('nama_user' => $nama_user));
    return $query;
}
```

and then use `num_rows()` function in controller

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`sizeof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)

**Model:** *(same as yours)*

```
public function selectRequestPerUser($nama_user) 
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', 
                        array('nama_user' => $nama_user));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$request = $this->model_request->selectRequestPerUser($this->session->userdata('nama'));
$total_rows = sizeof($request);
```